# Problems with migration from litespeed to nginx

Tags: php, nginx, litespeed

now we have lsws ent. working on Red Hat 5.5. I am trying to change it with nginx. problem is that there are different versions of php on system installed. how to force nginx to use the one which is used by lsws?

Answer (score 2):

you likely cant use the version of php used by lsws because it is compiled with the lsws isapi so wont connect to nginx via normal channels unless it has been compiled with fpm or fastcgi support

its probably safer to make sure the system version of php has that and use that so your not tied into keeping lsws if you make a full switch to nginx

Comment: thank you, anthonysomerset! problem is that system php installation missing some extensions, I'll try to add them, it shouldn't interfere with lsws php, right?

Comment: no because lsws php will be in a different location (and compiled from source anyway)